# what is the difference between _source and _all in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The difference between the two, who hold all of the fields, eludes me.

If my document has:

```
{"mydoc":
  {"properties":
      {"name":{"type":"string","store":"true"}},
      {"number":{"type":"long","store":"false"}},
      {"title":{"type":"string","include_in_all":"false","store":"true"}}

  }
}
```

I understand that `_source` is a field that has all the fields. But so does `_all`?
Does this mean that "name" is saved several times (twice? in `_source` and in `_all`), increasing the disk space the document takes?

Is "name" stored once for the field, once for `_source`, and once for `_all`?
what about "number", is it stored in `_all`, even though not in `_source`?

When should I use `_source` in my query, and when `_all`?

What is the use case where I can disable `_all`, and what functionality would then be denied?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as the difference between indexed fields and stored fields in lucene.

You use indexed fields when you want to search on them, while you store fields that you want to return as search results.

The `_source` field is meant to store the whole source document that was originally sent to elasticsearch. It's use as search result, to be retrieved. You can't search on it. In fact it is a stored field in lucene and not indexed.

The `_all` field is meant to index all the content that come from all the fields that your documents are composed of. You can search on it but never return it, since it's indexed but not stored in lucene.

There's no redundancy, the two fields are meant for a different usecase and stored in different places, within the lucene index. The `_all` field becomes part of what we call the inverted index, use to index text and be able to execute full-text search against it, while the `_source` field is just stored as part of the lucene documents.

You would never use the `_source` field in your queries, only when you get back results since that's what elasticsearch returns by default. There are a few features that depend on the `_source` field, that you lose if you disable it. One of them is the [update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update/). Also, if you disable it you need to remember to configure as `store:yes` in your mapping all the fields that you want to return as search results. I would rather say don't disable it unless it bothers you, since it's really helpful in a lot of cases. One other common usecase would be when you need to reindex your data; you can just retrieve all your documents from elasticsearch itself and just resend them to another index.

On the other hand, the `_all` field is just a default catch all field, that you can use when you just want to search on all fields available and you don't want to specify them all in your queries. It's handy but I wouldn't rely on it too much on production, where it's better to run more complex queries on different fields, with different weights each. You might want to disable it if you don't use it, this will have a smaller impact than disabling the `_source` in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks!
If i set a field to "index":"no", it still appears in "_all", right?
So, If I have no intention on doing a full text search on more than one specified field at a time, turning "include_in_all" to false on all my fields will save space, right?

Comment: I added some more thoughts to my answer in the meantime. The `_all` field is by default set as `"index":yes` and doesn't relate to the mapping of the other fields if not when using the `include_in_all` option. If you don't use `_all` field I'd disable it completely instead of setting all fields to `"include_in_all":false`.

Comment: Thanks, would disabling the `_all` field save considerable disk space? (it does seem it almost doubles the space needed, intuitively)

Comment: Yes it would save some space on disk, not as much as disabling the _source I guess. Usually stored fields in lucene are the biggest part of an index.

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly inverted indices take up some overhead for each <fieldname,fieldvalue AFTER analysis>-tuple + 1 bit per document containing said tuple. Story short: you save far less than disabling _source as @Javanna mentioned

Comment: javanna: you mentioned _all by default set as index: yes, right? But if I have a field using snowball analyzer, does it go into _all as well. In other word, inside _all the words should have already been tokenized the way I wanted, right? But I tested it, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Fei the `_all` has its own analyzer, of course it's indexed by default, but it doesn't use stemming. It uses the same standard analyzer for all the pieces that get indexed into it.

Comment: And would it be possible to change the analyzer used for the `_all` field in any way?
I don't have any use case about it but I'm curious anyway :)

Comment: Sure it is possible to change its analyzer through mappings (update mapping api)