# How to see the value of the _all field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch. Do we have any way to view the value of `_all` field, like other fields viewed in `_source`?

Comment: Do you mean the tokens or the raw, pre-analyzed text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on javanna's answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16526383/382774), the answer is no, you can't view the _all field. It is an indexed field, not a stored field.

Simplified, it's just the aggregated contents of the applicable fields from your document, and is the default field that ES uses for searching, when a target field isn't specified in your queries.

Comment: You could potentially see the `_all` field configuring it as stored, but you wouldn't see the tokens that get indexed, only the content of all fields that get included from the source documents, which you already know. If you want to see the content of the index, luke is the way to go (or the analyze api to simulate it).

Comment: I hadn't heard about `luke`, thanks! That said, I understood the question to mean retrieved documents via the ES API (eg. search or get), so I think I'm (we're) still right if we restrict the context appropriately. :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can, but you'd have to peek into the index directly to see what is stored there, using an index analyzer tool such as luke:

https://code.google.com/p/luke/

Hope this helps ;)