# Elasticsearch index a field without saving it

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I'd like to make a mapping e.g. a tweet and have a field like message,  user,  time.  Now I want ES to index all of these fields.  When I query for user:andi,  he will give me all the tweets with andi. So far it's pretty easy.  Now I want to have the same with message,  so all the message is indexed and searchable but I want to delete it or just index it without storing.  So I can search for a word from message but he shows only the time and the user.  How can I solve this?

Comment: In your queries you can restrict which fields to be returned. For example: `GET /my_index/my_type/_search?fields=time,user`

Comment: Well yeah.  But I'd like to outsource the "message" and just index it for searching the right tweet with the message.  Just imagine the message has 500mb and I don't to fill ES with this mb.  But I want to find the tweet by searching the content of the message

Comment: I think you can do it by specifically configuring the "_source" field: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html. "_source" is useful for updates and for highlights. If you just want to only search by that field, you'd need to exclude it from _source.

Comment: Also, check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526193/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-all-in-elasticsearch) as well. It has some very good info in it.